# richtextbox printing with fixed header and footer

Tags: wpf, printing, header, richtextbox, fixed

Hell Everybody,

I need to provide a facility like letters printing.for letter formats i used a richtextbox to create different formats(Templates).now i need to print this formats with header.Heder information will change always and header height should be fixed for the page.For header informtion displaying also i took one Richtextbox.now i want to merge these two richtext box information before printing.but i failed to maintained the fixed header,if i merge the textboxs information.

Suggest me,what way is better to handle this.